# search which other python files invoke a class defined in an given pythonfile

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, find, search

There is a set of python files in a folder. One file includes a class definition, for instance

```
Class DataGen:
```

How can I know which python file in this folder use this Class? Are there any linux command that can allows me do this kind of search?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41276151) all the ways that python could refer to the class?

Answer (score -1):

Try `grep -R DataGen .` to recursively search your working directory for  files that contain "DataGen".

Comment: If you use `grep -R` with `*.py` it will only recurse into directories that are named something that matches `*.py`, directories with a `.py` "extension", which is unlikely to do what you want... Instead, specify the current directory instead: `grep -R DataGen .`, that should be more helpful...